# highcharts highmaps parsing json data to display world map with rich info

Tags: jquery, highcharts, highmaps

I am working on Highcharts highmap.I take example of highmaps with rich info.Below is my code,in this world map chart working fine but info chart is not working.For refrence I am using below link,
https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/rich-info.When I am clicking on india plot info graph of india with last five month data.but graph not ploting,

```
$.ajax({
    //url: 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/highcharts/highcharts/v6.0.4/samples/data/world-population-history.csv',
    success: function () {

        var jsondata = {

           "data":[
              {  
                 "value":"27",
                 "code":"in",
                 "name":"india",
                 "last_five_month":[
                    {
                        "month":"Jan",
                        "vcount":"30"
                    },
                    {
                        "month":"Feb",
                        "vcount":"80"
                    },
                    {
                        "month":"Mar",
                        "vcount":"50"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {  
                 "value":"1",
                 "code":"ie",
                 "name":"ireland",
                 "last_five_month":[
                    {
                        "month":"Jan",
                        "vcount":"70"
                    },
                    {
                        "month":"Feb",
                        "vcount":"10"
                    },
                    {
                        "month":"Mar",
                        "vcount":"30"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {  
                 "value":"2088",
                 "code":"us",
                 "name":"united states",
                 "last_five_month":[
                    {
                        "month":"Jan",
                        "vcount":"90"
                    },
                    {
                        "month":"Feb",
                        "vcount":"20"
                    },
                    {
                        "month":"Mar",
                        "vcount":"40"
                    }
                 ]
              },
              {  
                 "value":"65778",
                 "code":"ca",
                 "name":"canada",
                 "last_five_month":[
                    {
                        "month":"Jan",
                        "vcount":"20"
                    },
                    {
                        "month":"Feb",
                        "vcount":"10"
                    },
                    {
                        "month":"Mar",
                        "vcount":"60"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }

         var mapChart;
         var countryChart;

        /* var data = [];
          var graphdata = [];

         $.each(jsondata.data, function(i, item) {
             $.each(item.last_five_month, function(x,item2) {

                 var graphval = [];
                 var last_five_month_array = [];

                 var month = item2.month;
                 var vcount = item2.vcount;

                 last_five_month_array.push(month);
                 last_five_month_array.push(vcount);

                 graphdata.push(last_five_month_array);

          });
        });
         console.log(graphdata);
         return false;*/

         var graphdata = [];
         var graphdataf = [];
         var month;
         var valuecount;
         var countries = {};

         /*$.each(jsondata.data, function (i, item) {
            var code = item.code;
         });
         return false;*/

         $.each(jsondata.data, function (i, item) {

                var graphval = [];

                var value = item.value;
                var code = item.code;
                var name = item.name;

               graphval.push(code);
               graphval.push(value);
               graphdata.push(graphval);

              $.each(item.last_five_month, function (j, itemval) {

                 /*var graphvaldata = [];
                 valuecount = itemval.vcount;
                 month = itemval.month;

                 graphvaldata.push(valuecount);
                 graphvaldata.push(month);

                 graphdataf.push(graphvaldata);*/

              });
                countries[item.code] = {
                name: item.name,
                code3: item.code,
                data: item.last_five_month
            };
         });

         var data = [];

        for (var code3 in countries) {
            if (countries.hasOwnProperty(code3)) {
             $.each(countries[code3].data, function (j, itemval) {
                 //var graphvaldata = [];
                 var value = itemval.vcount;
                 var month = itemval.month;

                 //graphvaldata.push(valuecount);
                 //graphvaldata.push(month);
                 //graphdataf.push(graphvaldata);

                //var value = null,
                //mon,
                //itemData = countries[code3].data,
                //i = itemData.length;

                /*while (i--) {
                    //if (typeof itemData[i] === 'number') {
                        value = itemData[i];
                        month = categories[i];
                        break;
                    //}
                }*/

                data.push({
                    name: countries[code3].name,
                    code3: code3,
                    value: value,
                    year: month
                });
              });
            }

        }
     // Wrap point.select to get to the total selected points
        Highcharts.wrap(Highcharts.Point.prototype, 'select', function (proceed) {
            proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
            var points = mapChart.getSelectedPoints();
            if (points.length) {
                if (points.length === 1) {
                    $('#flag').attr('class', 'flag ' + points[0].flag);
                    $('h2').html(points[0].name);
                } else {
                    $('#flag').attr('class', 'flag');
                    $('h2').html('Comparing countries');

                }
                $('.subheader').html('<h4>Historical population</h4><small><em>Shift + Click on map to compare countries</em></small>');

                if (!countryChart) {
                    countryChart = Highcharts.chart('country-chart', {
                        chart: {
                            height: 250,
                            spacingLeft: 0
                        },
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: null
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            tickPixelInterval: 50,
                            crosshair: true
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: null,
                            opposite: true
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            split: true
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                                animation: {
                                    duration: 500
                                },
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                                //threshold: 0
                                //pointStart: categories
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                $.each(points, function (i) {
                    // Update
                    if (countryChart.series[i]) {
                        /*$.each(countries[this.code3].data, function (pointI, value) {
                            countryChart.series[i].points[pointI].update(value, false);
                        });*/
                        countryChart.series[i].update({
                            name: this.name,
                            data: countries[this.code3],
                            type: points.length > 1 ? 'line' : 'area'
                        }, false);
                    } else {
                        countryChart.addSeries({
                            name: this.name,
                            data: countries[this.code3],
                            type: points.length > 1 ? 'line' : 'area'
                        }, false);
                    }
                });
                while (countryChart.series.length > points.length) {
                    countryChart.series[countryChart.series.length - 1].remove(false);
                }
                countryChart.redraw();

            } else {
                $('#info #flag').attr('class', '');
                $('#info h2').html('');
                $('#info .subheader').html('');
                if (countryChart) {
                    countryChart = countryChart.destroy();
                }
            }
        });
        // Initiate the map chart
        mapChart = Highcharts.mapChart('container', {

            title: {
                text: 'Population history by country'
            },

            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL/countries/1W?display=default">The World Bank</a>'
            },
            /*mapNavigation: {
                enabled: true,
                buttonOptions: {
                    verticalAlign: 'left'
                }
            },*/

            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'left',
                verticalAlign: 'bootom',
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            colorAxis: {
                type: 'logarithmic',
                endOnTick: false,
                startOnTick: false,
                min: 50000
            },

            tooltip: {
                footerFormat: '<span style="font-size: 10px">(Click for details)</span>'
            },
            credits: {
                  enabled: false
                },


                /*data: graphdata,
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
                joinBy: 'hc-key',
                allAreas: true,
                name: 'Random data',*/

            series: [{
                data: graphdata,
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
                joinBy: 'hc-key',
                name: 'Total Play',
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                states: {
                    select: {
                        color: '#a4edba',
                        borderColor: 'black',
                        dashStyle: 'shortdot'
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not refer your data properly - `countries[this.code3]` is always `undefined`.

You should consider initializing and converting your data like this:

```
      var data,
        dataRaw = countries[point['hc-key']].data;

      if (dataRaw) {
        data = dataRaw.map((p) => parseInt(p.vcount));
      }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b02gfrz1/

Comment: It working for me but my one issue is that catagories not get ploted on x-axis.I am looking to plot data for last three month like Jan,Feb,March

Comment: Yes, I didn't implement that. You need to extract categories from your data and assign them to `xAxis.categories` property.